# Tengo un problema con un script para calcular porcentaje

Tags: javascript

Tengo este pequeño script que cuando lo termine lo agregare a un proyecto. Pero solo me da el porcentaje del primer producto.

Explico es un formulario para introducir datos y tengo varios input, quiero calcular el Porcentaje de cada fruta del Total_Frutas y necesito que me muestre el resultado del Porcentaje en el input que corresponda.

`

```
function calcular() {
        try {
                var a = Number(document.getElementById("Total_Frutas").value) ||0;
                    b = Number(document.getElementById("Mango").value) ||0;
                    c = Number(document.getElementById("Guayaba").value) ||0;
                    d = Number(document.getElementById("Manzana").value) ||0;
                    e = Number(document.getElementById("Pera").value) ||0;
                    f = Number(document.getElementById("Fresas").value) ||0;
     
                                       
                document.getElementById("Porc_Mango").value = b*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Guayaba").value = c*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Manzana").value = d*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Pera").value = e*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Fresas").value = f*100/a;
 
            } catch (e) {}
}
```

`[image: Algo así serían los input:]

```
<form action="registro.php" name="" method="POST">
     <h2 align="center" class="form_titulo">
     
       <input type="text" name="" id="Total_Frutas" placeholder="Total_Frutas ....." step="0.01" oninput="calcular()">
      
       </h2>
     <p align="center">                   
                      <input type="text" name="" id="Mango" placeholder="Mango ..... " step="0.01" oninput="calcular()">
                      <input type="text" name="" id="% Mango" step="0.01">
       </p>
       
       <script type="text/javascript">

function calcular() {
        try {
                var a = Number(document.getElementById("Total_Frutas").value) ||0;
                    b = Number(document.getElementById("Mango").value) ||0;
                    c = Number(document.getElementById("Guayaba").value) ||0;
                    d = Number(document.getElementById("Manzana").value) ||0;
                    e = Number(document.getElementById("Pera").value) ||0;
                    f = Number(document.getElementById("Fresas").value) ||0;
     
                                       
                document.getElementById("Porc_Mango").value = b*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Guayaba").value = c*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Manzana").value = d*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Pera").value = e*100/a;
                document.getElementById("Porc_Fresas").value = f*100/a;
 
            } catch (e) {}
}
```

```js
<p align="center">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="Guayaba" placeholder="Guayaba" step="0.001" oninput="calcular()">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="% " step="0.001">
                       </p>
                      
                        <p align="center">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="Manzana" placeholder="Manzana" step="0.001" oninput="calcular()">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="% Manzana" step="0.001">
                      </p>
                          
                        <p align="center">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="Pera" placeholder="Pera" step="0.001" oninput="calcular()">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="% Pera" step="0.001">
                      </p>
          
                        <p align="center">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="Fresas" placeholder="Fresas" step="0.001" oninput="calcular()">
                          <input type="text" name="" id="% Fresas" step="0.001">                     
                        
                        <p align="center">                        
                        <p align="center">
                        <p align="center">
                                          
             <td align="center">
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML, cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola Enrique, por favor, comparte también el HTML relacionado para que sea un [mcve] y sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Una nota aparte: tal y como se están definiendo las variables dentro de la función, tendrán un alcance global (excepto `a`). Deberías usar comas para separar las definiciones en lugar de punto y coma.

Comment: Ya probe reemplazando los punto y comas por comas y hace los mismo, solo me devuelve el porcentaje del primer input.

Comment: Debes agregar el HTML necesario, tal como está tu código no es reproducible, en la parte de javascript haces mención a `input's` que están ausentes en el HTML

Comment: Nota aparte: un id con espacios no es muy buena idea que digamos... Además, como te han dicho, debes mostrar un [repro] del problema en cuestión: coloca los inputs faltantes en el HTML.

Comment: Ya agregue los otros input faltantes

Answer (score 0):

He notado que muchos controles que intenta obtener en `JavaScript` no existen, así que `document.getElementById(...)` te retorna un valor nullo, pero entonces intentas acceder a la propiedad `value` de un valor vació y ocurre una excepción, al poner `try/catch` lo que haces es que cuando ocurre un error, deja todo el código que hay en `try` y ejecuta el `catch`, ese e del `catch` contiene el error y se puede mostrar por consola:

```JavaScript
try{
  let comida=0;
  comida.arepa=21;
  console.log("no se mostrará");
}catch(e)console.log(e);
```

Veras que obtienes un error que la variable `arepa` no existe y te deja de ejecutar ese código.
Dicho esto, lo ideal seria primero hacer la comprobación de que exista el elemento:

```JavaScript
let obj=document.getElementById("no exist");
let n=0;
if (obj) n=Number(obj.value);
```

Esto funciona porque si el `if` recibe un valor `undefined`, `null` o `0` lo tratará como `false` y no se ejecuta. Intentemos resumir el código anterior:

`let n=Number((obj)?obj.value:0);`

Otro error es que intentas lo mismo. Que no existe(`null.value`). Esto te da error:

`document.getElementById("no exists").value=n*100/base;`

Para terminar de solucionar todo intentemos resumir un poco lo que hiciste para que no sea tan fastidioso y sea mas fácil modificar:

- Al ser un código repetitivo podemos usar una función o un bucle, yo elegiré usar lo segundo. Entonces necesitamos algo que recorrer, por suerte los id que definiste nos son de mucha ayuda así que a guardarlos en un `array`:)

```JavaScript
let pf_name=["Total_Frutas","Mango","Guayaba","Manzana","Pera","Fresas"];
let base=document.getElementById(pf_name[0]).value;
//El primer id no lo necesitamos
for (let i=1;i<pf_name.length;i++){
  //Ya dentro de bucle podremos hacer las comprobaciones mas fácil:
  let obj=document.getElementById(pf_name[i]);
  let n=Number((obj)?obj.value:0);
  
  //Ya tenemos el numero, ahora comprobamos la salida:
  obj=document.getElementById("Porc_"+pf_name[i]);
  if (obj) obj.value=(n!=0)?n*100/base:"No hay "+pf_name[i];
  else{
    //No existe así que lo creamos:
    obj=new DOMParser().parseFromString(/*Para convertir de texto a un objeto.*/
      `<input type="text" name="out-porc" id="${'Porc_'+pf_name[i]}" value="${(n!=0)?n:'No hay '+${pf_name[i]}}"/>`,
      "text/html"
     ).body.firstChild;//DOMParse retorna un documento completo así que debemos agarrar el primer elemento del body.
    document.querySelector("form").appendChild(obj);//Lo insertamos en el form
  }
}
```

El código completo se debería ver así o parecido(si seguiste mi ejemplo claro):

```html
<form action="registro.php" name="" method="POST">
  <h2 class="form_titulo" align="center">
<input type="text" name="" id="Total_Frutas" placeholder="Total_Frutas ....." step="0.01" oninput="calcular()">
  </h2>
  <p align="center">                   
<input type="text" name="" id="Mango" placeholder="Mango ..... " step="0.01" oninput="calcular()">
<input type="text" name="" id="% Mango" step="0.01">
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //name of products
  let pf_name=["Total_Frutas","Mango","Guayaba","Manzana","Pera","Fresas"];

  function calcular() {
let base=Number(document.getElementById(pf_name[0]).value || 0);

for (let i=1;i<pf_name.length;i++){
  let obj=document.getElementById(pf_name[i]);
  let n=Number((obj)?obj.value:0);
  //Ya tenemos el numero, ahora comprobamos la salida:
  obj=document.getElementById("Porc_"+pf_name[i]);
  if (obj)obj.value=(n!=0 && base!=0 && base!='')?n*100/base:"No hay "+pf_name[i];
  else{
    //No existe así que lo creamos:
    obj=new DOMParser().parseFromString(/*Para convertir de texto a un objeto.*/
      `<input type="text" name="out-porc" id="${'Porc_'+pf_name[i]}" placeholder="No hay ${pf_name[i]}" value="${(n!=0)?n*100/base:''}"/>`,
      "text/html"
    ).body.firstChild;//DOMParse retorna un documento completo, así que agarraremos el primer elemento del body.
     document.querySelector("form").appendChild(obj);//Lo insertamos en el form
  }
}
  }
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Uff, Bastante:)